# String between string and the next char that is not a number

Tags: python, string

I have a string like this:

```
rawString "sampleStringWithNumber/obj3453andBlabla"
```

And I would like to achieve this:

```
newString = "obj3453"
```

I know there is a lot of relevant question, and it wouldn't  be a problem if the next character after the `obj3453` would be static, but unfortunately the next char can be any letter (word) and there can be also more/less than 4 numbers.

So is it possible to do something like this:

```
 def find_between( s, first, last ):
    try:
        start = s.index( first ) + len( first )
        end = s.index( last, start )
        return s[start:end]
    except ValueError:
        return ""


print ((find_between(rawString, "/","the_next_string_thats_not_a_number")))
```

Basically I would like to pass a variable as the second argument that can be anything except a number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use regular expressions!

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "sampleStringWithNumber/obj3453andBlabla"
>>> re.search(r'/(.*?\d+)', s).group(1)
'obj3453'
```

The regular expression `/(.*?\d+)` searches for a slash, followed by a group that consists of any sequence of characters (non-greedy): `.*?`, followed by any number of digits: `\d+`.

`re.search` returns a match object (or None), and the first `.group` will be the result. In real code, you should probably first test if anything was found at all.

Comment: Great, thanks! Possibly could you tell me that will it work if there is no chars after the numbers? I mean there is no upcoming char or there is a whitespace.

Comment: Whitespace worked like this already, I fixed the "no upcoming char" thing in an edit.